# where to get Arduino WIFO101 library that supports WiFi.beginAP() on board MKR1000

Tags: programming, wifi, library, communication, compile

The sketch example from page ["Wifi.beginAP()"](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WiFi101BeginAP) causes compiler error because the return values are not defined for -WL_AP_LISTENING or -WL_CONNECT_FAILED.

Board: Arduino MKR1000 WiFi

Compiler:  Arduino IDE

Library: Github WiFi101 v0.9.1

Missing:  definition of "WL_AP_LISTENING" and "WL_CONNECT_FAILED"

ERROR....
beginAP.ino: In function 'void setup()':

beginAP:55: error: 'WL_AP_LISTENING' was not declared in this scope

```
if (status != WL_AP_LISTENING) {

              ^
```

Arduino WiFi101-MKS1000 examples\beginAP\beginAP.ino: In function 'void loop()':

beginAP:78: error: 'WL_AP_CONNECTED' was not declared in this scope

```
  if (status == WL_AP_CONNECTED) {

                ^
```

exit status 1
'WL_AP_LISTENING' was not declared in this scope

Answer (score 1):

It is AP_SimpleWebServer.ino at Github Wifi101 release 0.9.1 examples.
It builds ok by using the old definitions for .beginAP return values.
Problem is Arduino .beginAP page has example that relies on the LATEST Github WiFi101 ("0.9.1++" not released yet).
Also example AP_SimpleWebServer is missing from Arduino Wifi101 page.